# how to send value through function in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

```
public function index_pagination(){

        $this->load->library("pagination");
    $config = array();
    $config["base_url"]    = base_url("index/index");
    $config["total_rows"]  = $this->index_model->record_count();
    $config["per_page"]    = 2;
    $config["uri_segment"] = 3;

    // Styling pagination
    $config["full_tag_open"] = "<ul class='pagination'>";
    $config["full_tag_close"] = "</ul>";
    $config["next_tag_open"] = "<li>";
    $config["next_tag_close"] = "</li>";
    $config["prev_tag_open"] = "<li>";
    $config["prev_tag_close"] = "</li>";
    $config["num_tag_open"] = "<li>";
    $config["num_tag_close"] = "</li>";
    $config["cur_tag_open"] = "<li class='active'><a>";
    $config["cur_tag_close"] = "</li></a>";

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
    $data["page"] = $this->index_model->fetch_products($config["per_page"], $page);
    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
}

public function index(){

$this->index_pagination();

$this->load->view('frontend/index', $data);
}
```

How can I pass `$data["page"]` and `$data["links"]` from `index_pagination()` function to my view file through index function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this..

```
<?php

 public function index(){

    $data = array();
    $data = $this->index_pagination();

    $this->load->view('frontend/index', $data); 
    }

public function index_pagination(){

    $this->load->library("pagination");

    $config = array();
    $config["base_url"]    = base_url("index/index");
    $config["total_rows"]  = $this->index_model->record_count();
    $config["per_page"]    = 2;
    $config["uri_segment"] = 3;

    // Styling pagination
    $config["full_tag_open"] = "<ul class='pagination'>";
    $config["full_tag_close"] = "</ul>";
    $config["next_tag_open"] = "<li>";
    $config["next_tag_close"] = "</li>";
    $config["prev_tag_open"] = "<li>";
    $config["prev_tag_close"] = "</li>";
    $config["num_tag_open"] = "<li>";
    $config["num_tag_close"] = "</li>";
    $config["cur_tag_open"] = "<li class='active'><a>";
    $config["cur_tag_close"] = "</li></a>";

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
    $data["page"] = $this->index_model->fetch_products($config["per_page"], $page);
    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote two simple function in my controller, and used it. This is may not answer of your question but by using this at least you go DRY.

```
/**
 * This function used provide the pagination resources
 * @param {string} $link : This is page link
 * @param {number} $count : This is page count
 * @param {number} $perPage : This is records per page limit
 * @return {mixed} $result : This is array of records and pagination data
 */
function paginationCompress($link, $count, $perPage = 10) {
    $this->load->library ( 'pagination' );

    $config ['base_url'] = base_url () . $link;
    $config ['total_rows'] = $count;
    $config ['uri_segment'] = SEGMENT;
    $config ['per_page'] = $perPage;
    $config ['num_links'] = 5;
    $config ['full_tag_open'] = '<nav><ul class="pagination">';
    $config ['full_tag_close'] = '</ul></nav>';
    $config ['first_tag_open'] = '<li class="arrow">';
    $config ['first_link'] = 'First';
    $config ['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config ['prev_link'] = 'Previous';
    $config ['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="arrow">';
    $config ['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config ['next_link'] = 'Next';
    $config ['next_tag_open'] = '<li class="arrow">';
    $config ['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config ['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
    $config ['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $config ['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config ['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config ['last_tag_open'] = '<li class="arrow">';
    $config ['last_link'] = 'Last';
    $config ['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $this->pagination->initialize ( $config );
    $page = $config ['per_page'];
    $segment = $this->uri->segment ( SEGMENT );

    return array (
            "page" => $page,
            "segment" => $segment
    );
}


function userListing()
{
    $this->load->model('user_model');

    $this->load->library('pagination');

    $count = $this->user_model->userListingCount();

    $returns = $this->paginationCompress ( "userListing/", $count, 5 );

    $data['userRecords'] = $this->user_model->userListing($returns["page"], $returns["segment"]);

    $this->load->view('includes/header');
    $this->load->view("users", $data);
    $this->load->view('includes/footer');
}
```

Try this with your piece of code.
You can go for this repository to understand more https://github.com/kishor10d/Admin-Panel-User-Management-using-CodeIgniter